# Basic IR circuit question

Tags: infrared

I'm creating a basic IR circuit and trying to get a better understanding of its working.
What is the purpose of R2? and how would I calculate a new value for it if I was using a higher voltage supply instead?
[image: IR circuit]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the absence of R2, all the current flowing through D2 would pass into the base of Q1.  The resistor keeps Q1 switched off until D2 starts to conduct a little, which ensures that D1 is off in ‘dark’ conditions.  It also ensures a quick switch-off when D2 stops being illuminated.